# to-infinitive or conjunction?

Tags: grammar

What's the role of "to" in following sentence?Is it to-infinitive or conjunction?

> Harold resisted the opportunity **to** poke fun at the weird man.

Answer (score 0):

"To poke fun at the weird man" is a to-infinitive phrase in the sentence. The pattern of the use of the to-infinitive is:

verb (resisted) + noun (the opportunity) + to infinitive phrase (to poke fun .....).

Comment: thank you! could you explain grammatical rule of to-infinitive clause? Is it and adverb clause for "resist" or a adjective clause for "opportunity"?

Comment: It is a complement of the noun "opportunity". It's not obligatory, but it is always implied "An opportunity" doesn't make sense unless there is something that it is an opportunity _for_. The complement of "opportunity" is normally either "for _noun phrase_"  or "to _infinitive clause_ " This is a property of the word "opportunity", not a general rule of English grammar: some words are like "opportunity", but others have different requirements.